# Deployed Laravel project not running

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have a Laravel project working fine in Localhost.  After deploying it to a shared hosting server I am getting "prettyPrint is not defined" error. Can someone help me identify the problem.  PHP version on server is 7.1. Laravel 5.8 and using jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem was .htaccess file.   Replacing file solved the problem.